# Adding pagination on searched data in django using ajax call

Tags: java, django, ajax, django-pagination

I am trying to do pagination on the searched data but when clicked on the pagination option like on clicking second page i am not able to recieve the value of q and it throws error.

Comment: share your code of view and html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a minimal example of your code by reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you for your comment i appreciate your effort but i got my answer as i was not sending the searched value second time with page number i was getting error on second page but it is resolved.